# How do I minify CSS after updating a Grav theme's "un-minified" CSS file?

Tags: css, content-management-system, frontend, minify, grav

I'm using the *Saturn Site* theme from Grav (https://getgrav.org/downloads/skeletons) and want to change the background image of the home page (and eventually other styles). In the theme's custom CSS (`user/themes/saturn/css/custom.css`) I changed the background image, but the new image is not rendered unless I update both `custom.css` and `custom.min.css`.

I believe it is inappropriate to change both files; the system should generate a new version of the minified CSS. Reading the Grav docs (https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/asset-manager) I discovered that Grav provides

> an Asset Pipeline that can be used to minify and compress assets to reduce the number of browser requests, and also the overall size of the assets.

**How do I run this *pipeline* to update/minify the theme's CSS? Or do I need to install a separate CSS minifying tool?**

Additional information:
My `user/config/system.yaml` file includes this:

`assets:
  css_pipeline: false # The CSS pipeline is the unification of multiple CSS resources into one file
  css_minify: true # Minify the CSS during pipelining
  css_rewrite: true # Rewrite any CSS relative URLs during pipelining`

Answer (score 2):

Grav only minifies the files which are loaded in the theme.

According to https://github.com/getgrav/grav-theme-saturn/blob/develop/templates/partials/base.html.twig, `custom.min.css` is the loaded CSS file, so Grav will minify it, not `custom.css`.

You have 3 solutions:

1. Edit the line in `base.html.twig`
   `{% do assets.addCss('theme://css/custom.min.css') %}`
   to
   `{% do assets.addCss('theme://css/custom.css') %}`
   then you can add anything you like to custom.css and Grav will minify it for you.
   However if you do this, your change in `base.html.twig` will be lost when you update the theme.
2. You just add you CSS to `custom.min.css` and you don't need to minify it at all (although its name is `*.min.css`), Grav will help you minify it. This way your changes in `custom.min.css` will still be lost when you update the theme.
3. Create a child theme of this theme, override `base.html.twig` and apply the first or second solution above. This way your change will not be lost when you update the theme. However this requires Grav development skills.

Comment: Grav's documentation is really lacking. I thought Grav generates the custom.min.css , so everytime you modify custom.css, it would generate and overwrite custom.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

While in the root directory of GRAV try running `bin/grav clear`. That should update the minified CSS file as well.